# JavaScript factory for polymorphic objects approach

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymorphism, factory

I am trying to build up a jQuery plugin using a factory approach since I need two differing objects with the same API. However, most of the examples I see use an inheritance method where some prefabbed object is constructed and then modified according to that objects needs. My question is, why is every approach I've seen some prefabbed object being constructed and then modified rather than simply building the object according to the options and then returning the public side of it using closures as a hook back into the private state of said object.

I don't think this is a duplicate, I have been looking around for my answer and have been fairly unlucky so far

Examples that clearly show what I mean:
- [1](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/abstract-factory-design-pattern)
- [2](https://javascript.info/tutorial/factory-constructor-pattern)

Comment: Hmm ... What is your actual programming specific question? If you're asking why some examples are created as they are, that's not very specific, especially when there's no example of those ... examples.

Comment: it just seems like that's the way a polymorphic factory is done on every example. The programming question is why is it done that way if theoretically it'd take less code to just build the function with what you need and skip any kind of parent object that will be changed anyway. I'll edit some reference examples in that I have found

Comment: Still can't see a Q&A question. [Seen this?](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#designpatternsjavascript) ...